# Calling javascript from codebehind c# & Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Am unable to understand why Cannot the below javascript code is not called from code behind

I have a simple javascript block like this

```
  function callsCox(res) {
    alert(res);
   }
```

From my code behind :

```
 ....
 string res="COX23";
 string script = String.Format("callsCox({0})", res);
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Cox",script,true);
```

Am I missing anything? There aren't any exceptions or errors.

Comment: "this isn't working" is not a good description of the issue. _What_ isn't working? What is happening that you don't expect to happen? What isn't? Errors? Exceptions?

Comment: Hi Oded, Have edited my question, javascript code cannot be called from codebehind method. There arent any errors or exceptions.

Comment: first debug step should be to check the actual html coming from the server... does it contain a call to callsCox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` looks OK to me (might have missed something). Things to try

1. Add apostrophes to the call - it's coming through as an object. Try as a string

   string script = String.Format("callsCox('{0}')", res);
2. Is the string script `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` being called after an update panel partial postback. That could effect it
3. I have know functions not been found if they are in the same page. Try moving to an external js file. Don't asked me why this has resolved issues but it has a couple of times in the past for me.
4. Just for debug purposes take the function out of the equation all together, Try to get the alert working like this. It will at least isolate the problem if it does work

   this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Cox","alert('Does this work?')",true);
5. View the source of the page. Is the function even written into the page (or alert from point 4). It should be. If you put a breakpoint on the `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` method is it being hit? Seems like it might not be.

Apologies for not giving you a 'hey this is the solution' type of answer. I've had stuff like this in the past and I've found it a matter of stripping things down until the problem has been isolated. Someone else may be able to spot an immediate problem of course. Good luck.

Comment: Bucket, Tried following your steps described, strangely I cant even get the "alert", as you explained in step 4.

Comment: @Samuel. Just replace the this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript with the one on point 4. It should just embed the alert and the alert will come up. If that doesn't work then it can't be anything to do with the JS function. So it must be the register method at fault. I'll put an edit with another idea

Comment: Yes Buket, Now the alert is displayed.. only thing have changed is by replacing Cox with "script" and adding ';'  to end the alert.Let me try passing variables to the Js function.

Comment: @Samuel Looks like you're getting there. It might have been the ';'

Comment: Finally, Thanks a lot Buket. It is very silly mistake that I have made,All I need is a ";"  here  String.Format("callsCox('{0}');", res);......Finally it went through.Thanks a lot for sharing your time your steps really helped me to drill through.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public static void ShowAlert(Page page, String message)
{
    String Output;
    Output = String.Format("alert('{0}');",message);
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "Key", Output, true);
}
```